# Symfony2 choice field type - how can I generate a select element from an entity's data?

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to build a select input element from the following data:

```
$nameQuery = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.id, p.name FROM MyBundle:Person');
$names = $nameQuery->getResults();
```

Where each option is:

```
<select>
    <option value="{{ p.id }}">{{ p.name }}</option>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

I just don't know how to do it with Symfony2's built-in form types.  Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [form Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form),
In form builder, use this

```
$builder->add('type', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle:Person',
    'property' => 'name'
));
```